# Calculate degrees for movieclip rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I've a movieclip representing an arrow (with registration point in its middle). When I click a button, the arrow must point to a certain movieclip on stage. I use this code to execute the Tween:

```
TweenLite.to(arrow_clip,1,{rotation:degrees});
```

but I can't understand how to calculate the degrees. 
I tried the following with no luck:

```
var degrees =Math.atan2((clip.y-arrow_clip.y),(clip.x-arrow_clip.x))*(180/Math.PI);
```

Can you help me?

[EDIT]: I found the following is working but I can't completely understand why:

```
var degrees = -(Math.atan2(arrow_clip.x-clip.x, arrow_clip.y-clip.y))*(180/Math.PI);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the angle between two points, you can use:

`atan(dy/dx)` or `atan2(dy,dx)`

where `dy = to.y - from.y` and `dx = to.x - from.x`

This will get you radians from the horizontal axis, with 0 being to the right. The `rotation` property in Flash, however, is degrees from the vertical axis, with 0 being up. So you need to turn that into degrees, and the rotate by 90 degrees, because if `atan` says 0 radians then in Flash space, thats 90 degrees and -PI/2 radians = 0 degrees, and so on.

The following should work:

```
var degrees = Math.atan2(clip.y-arrow_clip.y,clip.x-arrow_clip.x)*(180/Math.PI) + 90;
```

The second example you posted works because it does does the 90 degree rotation by switching around the axes and inverting the result. It calculates from the `clip` to the `arrow`, then does `-atan(dx/dy)`. Notice that its `dx` over `dy` (instead of what its supposed to be) and negates the result. The essentially does the 90 degree rotation for you.

Comment: The second part (after the code) was quite clear to me. It's anything above (the part related to the Flash space) that I could not understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you "mirrored" the angle.

Comment: Uhm, "mirrored"... That is? What I don't understant is not the minus sign: I don't understand why the y argument of atan2 is the result of arrow_clip.x-clip.x.

Answer (score 0):

Your last solution does not compute the angle between (clip, arrow_clip), but rotates it by 90°C, that is PI/2.

Comment: My last solution works always but I don't understand why   :-)